# AS3 one-liner with conditionals

Tags: actionscript-3, math, median

How can I craft a one-liner return line that also has conditionals? For example, if I want to make a 'return the median' one:

```
//assuming sorted input array
return ((inputArray.length % 2) && (inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)] + inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1]) / 2) || inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1];
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: I'm all about one lining code when it makes the concept I'm trying to express *more* readable/understandable. But that doesn't seem to be what you are going for here... So, I gotta ask: dear god why?

Comment: I believe that a 'find the median' function won't need to be changed, and can be easily tested for bugs. One line will safe space. Also, I just want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the ternary operator:

```
return (inputArray.length % 2 != 0) ? (inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)] + inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1]) / 2 : inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1];
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if (inputArray.length % 2 != 0) {
    return (inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)] + inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1]) / 2;
} else {
    return inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1];
}
```

If you want to use only `&&` and `||`, you can use the following (which is not really a good programming style):

```
((inputArray.length % 2 != 0) || return inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1]) && return (inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)] + inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1]);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(condition || return value2) && return value1;
```

So, thanks to the [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of boolean operators:

- if `condition` is `true`, `return value2` is not evaluated and `return value1` will be executed.
- if `condition` is `false`, `return value2` will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a more readable version without repetitions, but with some variables.

```
var index:int = int(inputArray.length / 2);
var item1:Number = inputArray[index];
var item2:Number = inputArray[index + 1];
var median:Number = (item1 + item2) / 2;

return (inputArray.length % 2 != 0) ? median : item2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with modified conditions:

```
return ((inputArray.length % 2) && (((inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)] + inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1]) / 2) || inputArray[int(inputArray.length/2)+1]));
```